# Is it possible to add images in datagridview cell dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, image, datagridview

i am developing a small application in which i have to include images with other data from SQL but the images should be come from local disk depending on file name from database. is it possible to do it? how?

Answer (score 1):

use `TamplateField`

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
             <img src="<%#Eval("FileName")%>" alt="NoImage">
        </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Note you should set image tag source to relative path not physical path

**Edit**

in case of winforms as you mentioned in your comment you can use `DataGridViewImageColumn` in your `DataGridVeiw` and set its `DataPropertyName` property to a an Image instance.

check my simple example

```
class MyDataSource
{
    // its value come from your database but now I will set it manually
    public String imgurl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Image img
    {
        get
        {
            return Image.FromFile(imgurl);
        }
    }
}
```

in from load

```
List<MyDataSource> mydatasource = new List<MyDataSource>();
mydatasource.Add(new urls() { imgurl = @"C:\image1.jpg" });
mydatasource.Add(new urls() { imgurl = @"C:\image2.jpg" });
mydatasource.Add(new urls() { imgurl = @"C:\image3.jpg" });
mydatasource.Add(new urls() { imgurl = @"C:\image4.jpg" });

//bind this collection to your datagridview
dataGridView1.DataSource = mydatasource;
```

in this sample I set `DataPropertyName` of `DataGridViewImageColumn` to `img` property

Comment: oops i forgot to mention i am using windows forms

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you have the image urls in the database and want to display those images in the gridview. If that is so, my suggestion would be to add an "asp:Image" tag to the gridview statically and update the "ImageUrl" attr using "Bind" method.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: no i have image name in database  and i have to show image(stored in my hard drive) of that name in datagridview